# how to make git bash ask password when you do pull / push requests?

Tags: git

I use Git Bash on Windows. When I do pull / push requests, git does not ask for password, but it is very necessary. 
how can I mke this possible?

Comment: Does pulling/pushing work even though the password isn't entered?

Comment: are you using the https protocol?

Comment: Does `git config -l` output any `credential`options?

Answer (score 0):

run `git remote -v`

If your repo is hosted on something like Github, you should see a response as such:

```
    origin  git@github.com:username/repo.git (fetch)
    origin  git@github.com:username/repo.git (push)
```

This means you are on SSH protocol for your repo, and you need to switch to HTTPS:

```
    git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

This gets a bit more complicated if your are hosting the git server yourself.

Comment: ran. I get
origin  https://name@bitbucket.org/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://name@bitbucket.org/repo.git (push)

Comment: switch to HTTPS. `git remote set-url origin https://name@bitbucket.org/repo.git `